# Firebase 3.0 session persistance

Tags: session, firebase, persistence, firebase-authentication

It seems impossible to use session persistence in firebase 3.0.

This was possible in the previous version:
https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/login/password.html

> authWithPassword() takes an optional third parameter which is an
>   object containing any of the following settings:
>
> remember - String
> If not specified - or set to default - sessions are
>   persisted for as long as you have configured in the Login & Auth tab
>   of your App Dashboard. To limit persistence to the lifetime of the
>   current window, set this to sessionOnly. A value of none will not
>   persist authentication data at all and will end authentication as soon
>   as the page is closed.

In version 3.0 there is no mention of the optional 3rd parameter:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.auth.Auth#signInWithEmailAndPassword

> signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
> returns firebase.Promise
>   containing non-null firebase.User

Also, in the new console (https://console.firebase.google.com/) I cannot find the option to change the default persistence.

Answer (score 5):

It may also be worth mentioning that you need to wait for the auth state to resolve. Per the docs:

> The recommended way to get the current user is by setting an observer on the Auth object:

```
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user) {
  if (user) {
    // User is signed in.
  } else {
    // No user is signed in.
  }
});
```

Link to the docs here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/manage-users

Answer (score 3):

In 3.0, users are currently always persisted until signOut() is called (or the user clears local storage).

Comment: Can this behaviour be changed? I want to use sessionOnly, except when the user chooses to remember his session...
For a security critical application that will be used on shared computers, it is not good practice to automatically persist the session.

Or... How can I call signOut() when the session expires (when the browser closes)? I don't think this is possible...

Comment: Currently sessionOnly on web is not supported, but there is strong interest in supporting it in the future.

Answer (score 2):

Firebase Auth JS SDK now supports sessionOnly persistence. For more on this, check https://firebase.google.com/support/release-notes/js#4.2.0 and https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence

You can now specify or switch Auth state persistence before or after sign-in. For your case, you can specify session only persistence as follows:
`firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)`

Comment: While the link may answer the question, it will be good to add the necessary contents from the link to this answer along with citation to make this as answer even without a link. Please see [answer] for more details

Comment: Details to the answer have been added.