# Firebase Auth login state persistence is not working

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication

On an ionic/AngularJS/Cordova IOS app.

I'm trying to set a persistence login using mail/password (followed `Firebase documentation` : https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/auth-state-persistence). But I can't figured out what is wrong with my code. My app is starting on the login page, when a user is clicking on the "Connexion button", it's trigger the login function.

The login is working, but when I'm closing the app (without logging out), restarting it, I'm still on the login page. The login is not persistent.

So I guess, one problem, might be the persistency call not well placed...Is it ? According to this post : [Firebase 3.0 session persistance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37568644/firebase-3-0-session-persistance) it could have someting related to `firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(function(user)`, but I don't know...

```js
// EMAIL CONNEXION TRIGGERED WHEN CONNEXION BUTTON IS HIT

$scope.loginEmail = function($email, $password){
  
  firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION)
  .then(function() {
    var alertPopup;
    
    function signInSuccess(response) {
  
    $state.go("menu.VN");
    }

    function signInError(response) {
    
        var errorCode = null;
        errorCode = response.code;
        if ($email === ""){
             alertPopup = $ionicPopup.alert({
                    title: 'Something wrong...',
                    cssClass: 'pop',
                    template: '<div class="center-form">Need an email address...</div>'
                });   
        }
}

return firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword($email, $password)
  .then(signInSuccess)
  .catch(signInError);

     })
     .catch(function(error) {
    // Handle persistence Errors here.
    var errorCode = error.code;
    var errorMessage = error.message;
  });

};
```

```html
<label>
          <span>Email</span>
          <input type="email" placeholder="" ng-model="data.email">
</label>

<label>
          <span>Password</span>
          <input type="password" placeholder="" ng-model="data.password">
</label>
    
<button ng-click="loginEmail(data.email, data.password )">Connexion</button>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To persist your state, you should use `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL` and not `firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.SESSION`.

There are known issues with `localStorage` in Cordova iOS apps being volatile.
Firebase Auth used to rely on `localStorage` but the latest version uses more reliable `indexedDB` to persist the user state. When this is not available, it falls back to `localStorage`. In that case, you could use this [Microsoft plugin for indexedDB](https://github.com/Microsoft/cordova-plugin-indexedDB).

tldr; migrate to the latest version of Firebase Auth and use the Cordova `indexedDB` plugin when `indexedDB` is not available.