# Firebase auth isn't storing data in local storage

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-authentication, local-storage

My app successfully signs the user into Firebase when the user clicks on "Submit", but Firebase doesn't store the user auth data in local storage in Chrome. I checked and the user object is returned successfully by Firebase, and the program prints "user signed in" with the correct user ID. However, when I run "localStorage" in the console, the object isn't there, and the user authentication doesn't persist. I'm not sure why it's not working. Here is my code:

```
firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.LOCAL);

function authenticate(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    let email = document.getElementById("email").value;
    let password = document.getElementById("password").value;
    
    let result = firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
    .then(
        (user) => {
            alert("User: " + JSON.stringify(user));   //this works
        }
    )
    .catch(console.log);
}

firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged( function(user){
    if(user){
        console.log("user signed in");   //this works
        console.log("user id: " + firebase.auth().currentUser.uid);  
        window.location.href = "./calendar.html";
    } else {
        console.log("No user");
        window.location.href = "./index.html";
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm seeing the same thing, did you ever figure this out?

Comment: If the browser supports IndexedDB, firebase will store the credentials there rather than localStorage by default (which is the default): https://stackoverflow.com/a/51029091/197472

Comment: When I was working on this project, I never figured it out and ended up restructuring my website to be a single-page application. However, I just opened the project again, and for some reason, it seems to be working fine now. Now, Firebase is setting localStorage and every page has access to it. I'm not sure why it's working now and wasn't before. I'm still going to try and replicate the bug and will get back to you if I find anything.

Comment: Any chance you're using an old browser that doesn't support IndexedDB? Apparently localStorage is the fallback.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use localStorage

```
localStorage.setItem('userData', JSON.stringify(userDetail));
```

To get Data

```
JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('userData'));
```

To remove

```
localStorage.removeItem('userData');
```